# Compute sum of multiple row values to a different row in Java with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have  a table with 3 columns.(`Date,Name,Weight`)

```
Date       Name   Weight
2015-01-01    sam     100
2015-01-01    joy     100
2015-01-01    max     110
2015-01-02    sam     200
2015-01-02    max     100
```

When I enter a date, I want to get sum of whole weight to one row like following.

```
Date        Whole Weight
2015-01-01     310
2015-01-02     300
```

Comment: Do you want the mysql query for that? It is Select SUM(weight) from mytable where Date='2015-01-01'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select date, sum(weight) as whole_weight from your_table group by date;
```

if you wanna enter the date by yourself, do like that:

```
select date, sum(weight) as whole_weight from your_table where date='enter the date here';
```